# How to split this string to dict with python?

Tags: python, split

**String**

```
string1 = '"{ABCD-1234-3E3F},MEANING1","{ABCD-1B34-3X5F},MEANING2","{XLMN-2345-KFDE},WHITE"'
```

**Expected Result**

```
dict1 = {'{ABCD-1234-3E3F}' : 'MEANING1', '{ABCD-1B34-3X5F}' : 'MEANING2', '{XLMN-2345-KFDE}' : 'WHITE'}
```

Perhaps it is simple question,
Is there any easy method to split `string1` to `dict1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a one-liner, this will work:

```
>>> dict(tuple(x.split(',')) for x in string1[1:-1].split('","'))
{'{ABCD-1B34-3X5F}': 'MEANING2', '{XLMN-2345-KFDE}': 'WHITE', '{ABCD-1234-3E3F}': 'MEANING1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string1 = '"{ABCD-1234-3E3F},MEANING1","{ABCD-1B34-3X5F},MEANING2","{XLMN-2345-KFDE},WHITE"'
elements = string1.replace('"','').split(',')
dict(zip(elements[::2],elements[1::2]))
```

You can first split the original string and extract elements from it. Now you can pair element in odd and even positions and turn them into a dict.

Answer (score 0):

And here another one-liner alternative:

```
>>> string1 = '"{ABCD-1234-3E3F},MEANING1","{ABCD-1B34-3X5F},MEANING2","{XLMN-2345-KFDE},WHITE"'
>>> dict((nm, v) for nm,v in [pair.split(',') for pair in eval(string1)])
>>> {'{ABCD-1234-3E3F}': 'MEANING1', '{ABCD-1B34-3X5F}': 'MEANING2', '{XLMN-2345-KFDE}': 'WHITE'}
```

Comment: All answers could work, and this one is best, split without preprocess on `string1` and one-liner

Comment: @2000 Not sure why you dislike "preprocessing": it's almost never a good idea to use `eval` unless (1) it's the only way to do it and (2) you have no doubts about what the input will be.

Comment: @brianpck I'm not clear about what issue `eval` will cause ?

Comment: @2000 here's a good start: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html